# What are these thumbs up?

Tags: dont-get-fired

What are the thumbs up in my collection in Don't get Fired? What do they do?

[image: Screenshot of the thumbs]

Comment: I sent an email to the developer asking exactly the same question. Here is his response (copy/paste removing line breaks):
----------
It's a hidden feature.
(However, most people are already aware of it)
If you work hard the game, you will know naturally.
Hints, please handle the many tasks piled on your desk.
Then, you will soon get a thumb! :)
(Hint 2, if the other people on the side of your desk, please enter it!)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikia](http://dontgetfired.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Positions), concerning the position as president:

From this position you can get the 3rd thumbs up by giving away 500000 of YOUR money to your employees.

Comment: This is actually right. At least, it also says so on the Wikia page.